# Cant find model with id error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

[My screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSOcF.jpg)

I have messages speaker models.
I want to display number of messages each speaker posted on pages index page. When i insert @speaker = Speaker.find(params[:id]) it dispalys error Couldn't find Speaker with 'id'=.  I dont understand what am i doing wrong.

my pages controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @messages = Message.all.order("created_at DESC")

    @speakers = Speaker.all

    @speaker = Speaker.find(params[:id])
    @count = @speaker.messages.count
    @listeners = Listener.all
  end
  def about

  end
    def show
    @speaker = Speaker.find(params[:id])
    end

end
```

and my home view

```
<%= @count %>&nbsp;Messages
```

Comment: Try printing the value of params[:id] just before each *find*, make sure it is a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I need to see your routes.rb and the whole home view to better understand.  My guess is that you are not actually passing the parameter for it to find.

For example, if your route looks something like this example route:

```
  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
```

When you go to the URL products/1, it knows to pass the parameter id of 1 (`params[:id] = 1`) to the controller.  Otherwise, you need to pass it into the GET request somehow like through a link.  Since it is your home page, I doubt that is the intended set up of your app.

My guess is you are attempting to loop through all speakers on the home page.  In that case, you can achieve the same effect but with simpler code.  This is just a guess, but you may be able to do something like this in your controller and views:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @speakers = Speaker.all
  end
end

<% @speakers.each do |speaker| %>
  <%= speaker.name %>: <%= speaker.messages.count %> messages

  <ul>
    <% speaker.messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message.body %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

This will print out the speaker's name and message count and then all their messages, assuming you set up the relationship between them in your model.

Comment: Thank you. it worked, yes i wanted just to loop on my home page. I didnt realize i need to put it inside a loop first before displaying <%= speaker.messages.count %>

Comment: No problem!  Have you tried the Michael Hartl book yet?  It's pretty good for learning Rails and the online version is free.  You can find it here: https://www.railstutorial.org/book